# Directly open google map navigation in ios sdk

Tags: ios, google-maps, location

I want to open google map naviagation directly through googgle map App.
 currenly i am using the  code below

```
 NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:testURL]) {

        NSString *direction=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://?saddr=%@,%@&daddr=%@,%@&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&x-source=AirApp", @"18.9750", @"72.8258", @"23.0300",@"72.5800"];
                             NSURL *directionsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:direction];
                             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:directionsURL];
                             }
                             else {
                                 showAlert(AlertTitle, @"You don't have GoogleMaps App on this device. Please install it.");
                                 //NSLog(@"Can't use comgooglemaps-x-callback:// on this device.");
                             }
                             }
```

But that is showing only direction and after that i need to click on navigation button in the App , is there is any way so that i can open google map navigation 
directly.

Comment: the **canOpenURL** is open the map directly , k now what the problem u faced..

Comment: after opening the map i want that it should open navigation directly but it is showing the  direction and i need to click on navigation button .

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can you halp me out in this

Comment: Try to leave the saddr parameter blank and see if it helps

Comment: @BoazSaragossi thanks for suggetion but that also not worked.

Comment: I tried your code, and it works for me. If you are just need to open navigation in Google Maps app, you dont really need to add the `&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&x-source=AirApp` in your NSURL, you can try `http://maps.google.com/maps?` alternatively, which will open in web browser, you can also checked out my [gist code snippet](https://gist.github.com/ziyang0621/3fd49e78fd7287977441).